# Is it bad to use many packages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, module, package, composer-php

Sometimes a feature that I want to create for my `laravel` application already exists as a package.

It is easy to install them, but I am worried about their impact on the application performance.

What should I consider when choosing whether to install a package or develop a feature by myself?

Answer (score 3):

It's personal preference at the end of the day.

Some packages are well written, optimized and maintained and this gives you so many benefits:

- Reduced maintainence cost (i.e. you aren't 100% responsible for fixing the package code)
- Decreased development time (i.e. you don't have to write it)
- Increased functionality (i.e. they may have features you hadn't even thought of)

Other packages are poorly written, un-optimized and in some cases obsolete. These can have the opposite effect:

- Increased maintainence cost (i.e. the author isn't neccesarily going to fix an issue)
- Increased development time (i.e. you will probably have to learn their code base and fix issues yourself)

My advice would be to make sure that if it's a well respected author/company and their code base is activily being worked on (check github / npm / etc), then using the package will likely save you time and hassle in the long run.

You aren't likely to see any massive performance degredation by using composer packages over writing it yourself!